# weird behavior when merging one non-empty data.frame with an empty one

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have one non-empty data frame `df1`

```
df1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
V1 V2
1  5
2  6
3  7
4  8
")
```

and two empty data frames `df2.a` and `df2.b`, i.e.,

```
df2.a <- data.frame(V1 = integer(0), V2 = integer(0), V3 = integer(0), V4 = integer(0))


df2.b <- structure(list(V1 = NULL, V2 = NULL, V3 = NULL, V4 = NULL), row.names = c(NA, 0L), class = "data.frame")
```

where `df2.a` and `df2.b` looks almost no difference (the only difference is shown when using `dput(df2.a)` and `dput(df2.b)`)

```
> df2.a
[1] V1 V2 V3 V4
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> df2.b
[1] V1 V2 V3 V4
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

However, when I tried to merge `df1` with `df2.a` or `df2.b`, something weird occurs

```
> merge(df1,df2.a,all = TRUE)
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  5 NA NA
2  2  6 NA NA
3  3  7 NA NA
4  4  8 NA NA

> merge(df1,df2.b,all = TRUE)
  V1 V2 V4
1  1  5 NA
2  2  6 NA
3  3  7 NA
4  4  8 NA
```

As you can see, `V3` is dropped when merging `df1` with `df2.b`, while the desired one should be something like the output of `merge(df1,df2.a,all = TRUE)`.

Can someone explain a bit about this? Appreciated if there is a workaround to address the issue when using `merge` over `df1` and `df2.b`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a complex one. The mis-step occurs in [this line](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/8d5571f71ed163e85e3e1035a1f9b787197fea05/src/library/base/R/merge.R#L149) of `base::merge`:

```r
y <- y[c(m$yi, if (all.x) rep.int(1L, nxx), if (all.y) m$y.alone), 
            -by.y, drop = FALSE]
```

When you pass `df2.b` as the `y` argument to `merge`, this line actually produces an invalid data frame, as you can see in the browser:

```
Browse[2]> y
#>        V4
#> NA   NULL
#> NA.1 <NA>
#> NA.2 <NA>
#> NA.3 <NA>
#> Warning message:
#> In format.data.frame(if (omit) x[seq_len(n0), , drop = FALSE] else x,  :
#>  corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs
```

If we trace the logic through, we can see that we can reproduce the error outside the debugger by calling:

```r
df2.b[c(1, 1, 1, 1), -c(1:2), drop = FALSE]
#>        V4
#> NA   NULL
#> NA.1 <NA>
#> NA.2 <NA>
#> NA.3 <NA>
#> Warning message:
#> In format.data.frame(if (omit) x[seq_len(n0), , drop = FALSE] else x,  :
#>  corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs
```

Whereas, we don't get this problem for `db2.a`:

```r
df2.a[c(1, 1, 1, 1), -c(1:2), drop = FALSE]
#>      V3 V4
#> NA   NA NA
#> NA.1 NA NA
#> NA.2 NA NA
#> NA.3 NA NA
```

So why is this? Even though `df2.a` and `df2.b` look the same when you print the data frame, they are *not* the same. An empty numeric vector isn't quite the same as `NULL`. The main difference (the one that causes the problem here) is that indexing an empty numeric vector gives you a non-zero length of `NA` values, whereas NULL gives you a single `NULL` value.

```r
df2.a$V1[1:4]
#> [1] NA NA NA NA

df2.b$V1[1:4]
#> NULL
```

So I guess this is expected behaviour. The problem is that R allows `NULL` as a dataframe column at all. I'm surprised this kind of thing doesn't happen more often.

Comment: R doesn't really allow `NULL` as a data frame column, you can't define a `NULL` column using the idiomatic constructor `data.frame()` or even `x["col"] <- list(NULL)`. I believe we can thus consider this object corrupted. However the print method (and even the as.data.frame method) don't fail on such object. We might argue it's a shortcoming (in this case I think I would!) but validating objects takes ressources so that might be debatable if it's a bug or not.

Answer (score 5):

I tracked the cause of this issue and found that this mistake arises in the following section of `merge.data.frame`:

```
y <- y[c(m$yi, if (all.x) rep.int(1L, nxx), if (all.y) m$y.alone), 
            -by.y, drop = FALSE]
```

To show the problem, try the following code:

```
df2.b[rep(1, 4), -(1:2), drop = FALSE]
#        V4
# NA   NULL
# NA.1 <NA>
# NA.2 <NA>
# NA.3 <NA>
# Warning message:
# In format.data.frame(if (omit) x[seq_len(n0), , drop = FALSE] else x,  :
#   corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs

df2.a[rep(1, 4), -(1:2), drop = FALSE]
#    V3 V4
# 1: NA NA
# 2: NA NA
# 3: NA NA
# 4: NA NA
```

Therefore, this issue is caused by `[.data.frame`. A section of the source code of `[.data.frame` is:

```
for (j in seq_along(x)) {
        xj <- xx[[sxx[j]]]
        x[[j]] <- if (length(dim(xj)) != 2L){
            xj[i]
        }else{ xj[i, , drop = FALSE]}
    }
```

here, `x` is the resulting data.frame to be returned. It now has columns V3 and V4 only. `xx` is a copy of the input data.frame (df2.b in our case). This for-loop will first assign `NULL` to column 1 of `x`. Thus, `V3` is deleted at this step. Next, the for-loop assigns `NULL` to the column 2 of `x`. However, as V3 is gone, there is no column 2. Therefore, x will not be affected. That's why we get the unexpected results.

If we set `df1` and `df2.b` to `data.table`, merging of them will throw an error. It seems that `data.table::merge` treats such cases more strictly. The error message will help us avoid getting unexpected results.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to provide an answer as complete as I can...

(When I posted the answer, I noticed I joint the party too late :D I'll leave the answer anyway as, I hope, it'll provide another interesting point of view)

---

## DEBUG MERGE

Let's start by looking at the `merge` function. Specifically, the method that here gets called which is `merge.data.frame` (exported function of the `base` package).

If you debug `merge.data.frame(df1,df2.b,all = TRUE)`, you'll see at line 124 that this gets called:

```
y <- y[c(m$yi, if (all.x) rep.int(1L, nxx), if (all.y) m$y.alone), 
   -by.y, drop = FALSE]
```

`y` is identical to `df2.b`.

Since `m$yi` is equal to `integer(0)`,  `all.x` is `TRUE`, and `all.y` is `FALSE`, this can be simplified to:

```
y[rep.int(1L, nxx), -by.y, drop = FALSE]
```

The output of it is:

```
       V2   V4
NA   NULL NULL
NA.1 <NA> <NA>
NA.2 <NA> <NA>
NA.3 <NA> <NA>
Warning message:
In format.data.frame(if (omit) x[seq_len(n0), , drop = FALSE] else x,  :
   corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs
```

So this is the behind-the-scene "problem" that `merge` tells us nothing about.

Let's dig into it.

First of all the actual output is not that, that's just the default `print.data.frame` method that tricks our eyes.

The output of

```
unclass(y[rep.int(1L, nxx), -by.y, drop = FALSE])
```

is

```
$V4
NULL

attr(,"row.names")
[1] "NA"   "NA.1" "NA.2" "NA.3"
```

NULL doesn't get duplicated, which makes sense since you can't do a vector with two NULL

```
identical(c(NULL, NULL), NULL)
#> TRUE
```

As the warning says, the data.frame is corrupted and the printing may be faulty (which it is!).

That's because the data.frame was created in a tricky way with `structure()` instead of `data.frame()` or `as.data.frame()` which wouldn't have led you to that structure.

So this is the story of how you get to one column only.

The question is why?

For that we need to go look at the function `[.data.frame`.

---

## DEBUG [.data.frame

Let's observe some behaviors first.

```
> df2.b[1,]
     V2   V4
NA NULL NULL
> df2.b[,1]
NULL
> df2.b[,1, drop = FALSE]
[1] V1
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> df2.b[1,1]
NULL
> df2.b[1,1, drop = FALSE]
data frame with 0 columns and 1 row
> df2.b[1,1:2]
     V2
NA NULL
> df2.b[c(1,1),1:2]
       V2
NA   NULL
NA.1 <NA>
Warning message:
In format.data.frame(if (omit) x[seq_len(n0), , drop = FALSE] else x,  :
   corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs
```

The last three look pretty unexpected.
In particular the last one is our case. The same we saw before.

if you try to debug:

```
debugonce(base:::[.data.frame)
df2.b[c(1,1),1:2]
```

you'll find at line 109 this code:

```
 for (j in seq_along(x)) {
  xj <- xx[[sxx[j]]]
  x[[j]] <- if (length(dim(xj)) != 2L) 
   xj[i]
  else xj[i, , drop = FALSE]
 }
```

More readable:

```
 for (j in seq_along(x)) {
  xj <- xx[[sxx[j]]]
  x[[j]] <- if (length(dim(xj)) != 2L) xj[i] else xj[i, , drop = FALSE]
 }
```

At that point, the variable are as follow:

```
x = list(V1 = NULL, V2 = NULL)
xx = df2.b
sxx = 1:2
i = 1:2
```

If you run the for loop with those variables you will get that x is:

```
> x
$V2
NULL
```

Looks like we found the source of the disappearing column.

Now, where is exactly the problem?

When `j == 1`, `x[[j]] <- ...` is equal to `x$V1 <- NULL` which in R allows you to delete the element V1 from a list. Therefore x becomes a list with only one element, this:

```
> x
$V2
NULL
```

When `j == 2`, `x[[j]]` doesn't exist anymore because at the first loop the first item was deleted and now only one is available. Therefore R is trying to assign a new second item, but since you can't assign a NULL as item [like this: `x[[2]] <- NULL`], x will not change.

Therefore you have only one column.

---

## SUM UP

The reason why `merge` has a weird behavior is because you created your dataframe in an improper manner.

`merge` doesn't tell you that the dataframe is actually corrupted and it does stuff even when it wouldn't be supposed to.

Ultimately, it's `[` and its way to deal with subsetting that defines the final loss of one of the columns.

---

## DPLYR

Honestly, just use `dplyr::full_join(df1, df2.b)`. It gives nothing for granted and it actually results in the error you would have expected from the beginning:

```
> dplyr::full_join(df1, df2.b)
Joining, by = c("V1", "V2")
Error: All columns in a tibble must be vectors.
x Column `V1` is NULL.
x Column `V2` is NULL.
x Column `V3` is NULL.
x Column `V4` is NULL.
```